# Third party WCF Service is throwing exception with error code: 10060 when called from IIS hosted application

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a third Party WCF service which I am able to call when my application is using IIS Express but when I host my application on Local IIS and calling to that WCF service it throws exception:

**"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"**

The service is also giving me result very quickly when I consume it from **console application & SOAP UI**

So what I think this is not a data related issue rather it is something related to **IIS (version 10).**

**The issue comes up when I hosted my application on Local IIS**

this is my config file

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IABCDPaymentService"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Service.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IABCDPaymentService"
    contract="BankServiceWCF.IABCDPaymentService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IABCDPaymentService" />
</client>
```

Looking for help on my issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to reach the wsdl from a browser?

Comment: yes Kye i am able to reach the wsdl from a browser.The issue was that i was not able to consume it when i was using local IIS.So i found the solution  and the problem was with administrative rights.when i provided the rights it works!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that i was not able to consume it when i was using local IIS.So i found the solution and the problem was with administrative rights.when i provided the rights it works!